# Create account and Login

Tags: java, class, instance

im having some trouble figuring out how i should approach this task. I would like to create an option to create an account and then have a login section. I am trying to figure out how to pass the information to the login class as i would like to be able to login without creating a new account every time. im not sure if this current code would allow for multiple accounts at the same time. I am open to suggestions if so on how to do that, but im fine with one account.
Here is my code so far:

**CreateAccount class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreateAccount{
    public static void main(){
       CreateAccount obj1 = new CreateAccount();
       obj1.accountNumberPin();
    }
    public void accountNumberPin(){
       System.out.println("create a six digit account number: ");
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int accNum = input.nextInt();    
       System.out.println("create four digit pin: ");
       Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
       int accPin = input2.nextInt();
    }
    public int getAccNum(){
        return accNum;
    }
    public int getAccPin(){
        return accPin;
    }
}
```

**Login Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Login{
    public void login(){
        CreateAccount test= new CreateAccount();
        int theaccNum = test.getAccNum();
        int theaccPin = test.getAccPin();
        System.out.println("Enter account number: ");
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accNumberInput= input1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter account pin: ");
        Scanner input2= new Scanner(System.in);
        int accPinInput = input2.nextInt();
        if(accNumberInput==theaccNum && accPinInput == theaccPin){
           System.out.print("1 2 1 2 this is just a test");
        }               
    }
}
```

PS, i know there is an issue currently with the get methods

Comment: Strange design. You should separate data from functionality. Login and create account separate from the user data.

Comment: you should to store your data in a file or using a database @Johnm

Comment: @Johnm `I would like to be able to login without creating a new account every time.` Obviously you have to store the details of your newly created account somewhere right? Be it a file or a database.

Comment: Do you want to save the accounts across restarts of the app? or just during a single run of the app (ie have the ability to create an account, login, etc .. but if you restart then they are gone?)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by having an Account class that only contains the data of the account:

```
class Account {
    
    private final int number;
    private final int pin;

    public Account(int number, int pin) {
        this.number = number;
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public int getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

}
```

Then implement the logic in another class. This class can maintain a list of the created accounts. That list will persist as long as you don't stop the program. (if you need persistence across restarts then you need some kind of storage, that is a file or a database).
Here is an example where I tried to keep as much of your code as possible:

```
public class Main {

    private static final Map<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1 - Create an account");
            System.out.println("2 - Login into an account");
            System.out.println("3 - List account numbers");
            System.out.println("4 - Quit");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = input.nextInt();

            if (choice == 1) {
                createAccount();
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                login();
            } else if (choice == 3) {
                listAccountNumbers();
            } else if (choice == 4) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice");
            }
        }

    }

    private static void createAccount() {
        System.out.println("create a six digit account number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("create four digit pin: ");
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accPin = input2.nextInt();

        Account account = new Account(accNum, accPin);

        accounts.put(accNum, account);
    }

    private static void login() {
        System.out.println("Enter account number: ");
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int accNumberInput= input1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter account pin: ");
        Scanner input2= new Scanner(System.in);
        int accPinInput = input2.nextInt();

        Account account = accounts.get(accNumberInput);
        if(account.getPin() == accPinInput) {
            System.out.print("Valid credentials for account number " + account.getNumber());
        } else {
            System.out.print("Invalid credentials for account number " + account.getNumber());
        }
    }

    private static void listAccountNumbers() {
        accounts.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Account deposit(double amount) {

   balance += amount;

   return new Account(getID(), getCustomer(), getBalance());

}

public Account withdraw(double amount) {

    if(balance >= amount) {

        balance -= amount;

    }

    return new Account(getID(), getCustomer(), getBalance());

}
```